# retrieving data from a specific column in php/MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I'm using WordPress with XAMPP. I'm trying to fetch the post title from a column called post_title from a table called ltport_posts by using `mysqli_fetch_row()` function. The connection with the database is working just fine. However, post titles don't seem to be written in the news ticker. Now I know that `$row` variable is an enumerated array, so we should write the offset number to access the column. It should be noted that the while loop is working since I have four rows in the ltport_posts and four `<div>`'s are generated (browser's inspect element is showing me that). But the whole tag is empty:

```
<div class="ticker-wrap">
<div class="ticker">
<div class="ticker__item"> </div>
<div class="ticker__item"> </div>
<div class="ticker__item"> </div>
<div class="ticker__item"> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the php/HTML code:

```
 <div class="ticker">
        <?php $query="SELECT post_title from ltport_posts";
        if($result=mysqli_query($conn,$query))
        {
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
            {?>
            <div class="ticker__item"><?php printf("%s", $row[5]); ?> </div>
        <?php }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);?>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you use query_post in wordpress?

Comment: @UmairHamid I'd like that to be a last resort, I'm trying this as an educational thing

Comment: Use `$row[0]` instead `$row[5]` !!

Comment: @Saty IT WORKED!!! can you tell me how did you know that???

Comment: Please debug and print $result so that it will easy to give you proper solution.

Comment: print the $row to know data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mysqli_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)

> mysqli_result::fetch_row -- mysqli_fetch_row — Get a result row as an
>   enumerated array

Your query is

```
$query="SELECT post_title from ltport_posts";
```

You just fetch `one column` from your query. So you will get only `$row[0]` .It's indexing start from 0

```
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
            {?>
            <div class="ticker__item"><?php printf("%s", $row[0]); ?> </div>
        <?php }
```

For  fetching multiple column

```
$query = "SELECT column1, column2,column3,column4 FROM City ORDER by ID DESC";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1],$row[3], $row[4]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not an associative array.

Comment: Where I use `associative array.`??

Comment: The comment says `/* fetch associative array */`, but fetches a numerical indexed array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
// Prepare the query
$stmt = "select column FROM table";

// Execute it...
$result = mysqli_query($stmt);

// Fetch Results
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

// Output single column
echo $row['column'];
```

And of course you can loop it through as well with multiple results. mysqli_fetch_assoc will return an array where the keys are the column names.